# undefined symbol and rebooting linux

Tags: shared-library

I am just qurious about this question.

Let's assume, someone has an `undefined symbol` error when starting a program. To solve that problem, someone could use tools like `ldd`, `ldconfig`, `nm` or some other, to find out, which library must be replaced to start that program again.

But let's assume another situation: The user of the program reboots the operation system and then starts the program and there is no `undefined symbol` error, i.e. the program starts properly. This could only be the case, if the right library (with that symbol) would exist already on the system.

- Is that possible on linux?
- And if yes, under which circumstances?
- What is done during a reboot on linux system in more detail concerning shared libraries?

Comment: Can be a bit more specific about what exactly the problem is?

Answer (score 1):

Two situations come to mind:

- Update of library while a process using this library is running. The process will see the old version of that library until it is restarted.
- Mounting a device on an already used mount point. Processes running in that mount point keep their old view.

Both situations are rectified with a reboot, but I'm not sure it applies to your situation.